# Why there is a mismatch between duration bar and the composite layer function

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I'm using Chrome timeline to analyze a website's performance. There is one thing I couldn't understand. I assume the horizontal bar with duration 53.5ms represents Chrome's "frame" operation(https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline#frames-mode). Shouldn't the "frame" include all the operation? Why the Green composite bar is NOT fully covered by the duration bar?

Thanks.